# How to show previously selected option in flask/jinja?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, crud

Working on the update part of my CRUD flask app and I don't know how to make the select option show what had been selected when the user was originally created.

Here is my select on my update page:

```
<select class="form-select" name="dojo_id">
{% for dojo in dojos %}
    <option value="{{ dojo.id }}">{{ dojo.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Here's my routes:

```
@app.route('/update/ninja/<int:id>') 
def update_ninja(id):   
    data = { 
        "id": id 
    }

    return render_template("update_ninja.html", ninja = ninja.Ninja.get_one(data), dojos = dojo.Dojo.get_all())  


@app.route('/update/ninja', methods=['POST']) 
def update_ninja_form():
    ninja.Ninja.update_one(request.form)

    return redirect(f"/view/dojo/request.form['dojo_id']")
```

So the select will show all the available options, it just doesn't default to the option that was already selected when originally created. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Send the selected id (selectedId) to the template and do this:

```
{% for dojo in dojos %}
    <option value="{{ dojo.id }}" "{{'selected' if dojo.id == selectedId else ''}}">{{ dojo.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```